# Solving a complex equation $z^4=-\sqrt 3 + i$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

> Find all the solutions of the equation :
> $$z^4=-\sqrt 3 + i$$

I tried solving this by using the 4th root and then, using sin and cos to find a final answer, but I don't think that this is how you solve it. Can you help?

Comment: you can find the picture if you click the title, im new on this site im sorry, i don't know how to type with mathematical characters in the text

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a Mathjax tutorial.  I would suggest converting to polar coordinates and then taking the fourth root

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

The general method to determine the $n$-th roots of a complex number $Z$ consists in first writing it in complex exponential notation:
$$z=r\,\mathrm e^{i\theta}\qquad(0\le\theta<2\pi, r\in\mathbf R^+)$$
and solving for $u^n=Z$ with $u=\rho\,\mathrm e^{i\varphi}$, leads to
$$\begin{cases}
\rho^n=r \\
n\varphi\equiv \theta\mod 2\pi
\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}
\rho=r^{1/n} \\
\varphi\equiv \frac\theta n\mod \frac{2\pi}n
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle-\sqrt3+i=2\left(-\frac{\sqrt3}2+\frac12i\right)=2\left(\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}6\right)+\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}6\right)i\right)$